# After App Engine HRD Migration my application will not load anyone know whats wrong?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've just tried to migrate (I have not done the alias bit yet) but Im getting 500 errors when I try to run the App.

The is a stack of errors in the Log, which suggest that the server part is just not running, or isn't there or something.... I have included the errors in the dashboard below and one of the critical errors in the log is:

> 2013-04-06 17:14:44.584 Uncaught exception from servlet
>   javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed. at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMa

```
Errors           URI Count % Errors

/process/actions     6      100%
/demo                5      100%
/Login/admin         4      100%
/images/hborder.png  3      100%
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I did a "clean build" of the project and redeployed it, and then it SEEMED to start working, however none of the indexes are right, so I am having to rebuild them manually.. not sure what happened there, but I dont have time to look into it I need to get live again ASAP!